# Django Auto Increment Field Non Pk

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

How to make the model so that each order that a customer submit is gonna be auto incremented (ie. order_number) without messing with the order obj primary_key?

#### Models.py

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customerID = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

#### Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = OrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

#### views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from .models import *
from .serializers import *

class CustomerListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

class CustomerDetailView(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

class OrderListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Order.objects.filter(customer_id=self.kwargs["pk"])
        return queryset
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

class OrderDetailView(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer 

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Order.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
        return queryset
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', CustomerListView.as_view(), name=''),    
    path('<int:pk>/', CustomerDetailView.as_view(), name=''),    
    path('<int:pk>/orders/', OrderListView.as_view(), name=''),    
    path('<int:customer_pk>/orders/<int:pk>/', OrderDetailView.as_view(), name=''),    
]
```

#### JSON Example

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "order": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "order_name": "fruit",
                "order_number": 1,
                "customer": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "order_name": "chair",
                "order_number": 2,
                "customer": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "order_name": "pc",
                "order_number": 3,
                "customer": 1
            }
        ],
        "customer_name": "john doe",
        "customerID": "81498"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "order": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "order_name": "phone",
                "order_number": 1,
                "customer": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "order_name": "car",
                "order_number": 2,
                "customer": 2
            }
        ],
        "customer_name": "jane doe",
        "customerID": "81499"
    }
]
```

If i need to submit more file such as seriallizers.py etc please let me know. Thank you in advance.

#### Edit

Adding a few more files.

#### Solution

The answer from ilyasbu is working but i need to change this line
`last_id = self.objects.all().aggregate(largest=models.Max('display_id'))['largest']` into
`last_id = Order.objects.filter(customer=self.customer).aggregate(largest=models.Max('display_id'))['largest']`

Comment: Hi marc_s, the costumer spelling is from the initial question that i forgot to change as you can see other than the model and json example every customer spelling is corrected. Also i saw your about page and it's really helpful especially for beginner like me so thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think could work is using an `IntegerField` (pretty much what an `AutoField` uses under the hood), and increment that on the model's first save (before it's ever put into the database).

example:

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):

    # This is what you would increment on save
    # Default this to one as a starting point
    display_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    # Rest of your model data

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This means that the model isn't saved to the database yet
        if self._state.adding:
            # Get the maximum display_id value from the database
            last_id = self.objects.all().aggregate(largest=models.Max('display_id'))['largest']

            # aggregate can return None! Check it first.
            # If it isn't none, just use the last ID specified (which should be the greatest) and add one to it
            if last_id is not None:
                self.display_id = last_id + 1

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi ilyasbbu, thank you for the comment.
I've tried your solution but it gives me this error
`AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Order instances`
Do you know why it happens?

Comment: I don't know how you had implemented this, maybe if i see the code I can say why.

Comment: Should i show all the code for it like the serializers.py etc?

Comment: yes in the code

Comment: I've added them. Would you be so kind to review it again? Really appreciated the help so far.

Comment: make sure you have added, I can't see any, maybe you missed

Comment: I've added them in the main question. I don't know why you can't see them tho.

Comment: your model isn't changed from the last edit

Comment: Because the model is the exact same model. I only add the other file like serializers, views and urls

Comment: Hey ilyasbu, it seems like your answer is working for me but i need to change this line
`last_id = self.objects.all().aggregate(largest=models.Max('display_id'))['largest']` into `last_id = Order.objects.all().aggregate(largest=models.Max('display_id'))['largest']`.  Thank you so much dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AutoField. django documentation speak about that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#autofield

Comment: Thank you for the comment but when i tried using autofield it simply gives me this error
`ValueError: Model temp.Order can't have more than one auto-generated field.`

Answer (score 0):

You could override the save function when an order is created and set the order number at that point based on the maximum of the other customer orders

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            # get all your customers orders and get the last order number
            last_order = self.customer.order.all().order_by('order_number').last()
            if not last_order:
                self.order_number = 1
            else:
                self.order_number = last_order.order_number + 1
        
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment but it gives me this error
~~~
  File "/home/mrezaananta/Documents/GitHub/temp-backend/temp/models.py", line 29, in save
    self.order_number = last_order.order_number + 1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'order_number'
~~~
Do you know why it happens?

Comment: @mRezaAnanta its because when you create a customers first order `last_order` will be `None`. I have updated the answer to deal with this.